# Undefined method 'model_name' when attempting to use Simple Form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am attempting to get a form generated by simple-form in my modal, however I keep running into the following error upon loading the page.

```
 undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Here is the simple code I was using to try to generate the form

**_header.html.erb** (under the view_pages_controller)

```
<%= simple_form_for @update do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :lang %>
  <%= f.input :book %> #temp, just for testing simpform
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I am pretty sure the problem lies with my controller code

**updates_controller.rb**

```
class UpdatesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @update = current_user.updates.build(params[:update])
    if @update.save
      flash[:success] = "Update successful"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Failed to update, please try again"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

**update.rb**

```
class Update < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book, :user_id, :lang, :round_id

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated. I know my code sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `@update` is null in your view. You should clarify which action renders this view, and set value to `@update`. The create action only sets it based on the params, and then redirects to root.

Comment: The modal is currently in the header until I can refactor it so the view is generated by the ViewPages controller. Just tried adding @update = current_user.updates.build to the ViewPages home function but I just get "Undefined method 'updates' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: This error is because your `current_user` is nil. Which controller and which action renders the view? How you normally get the Update object?

Comment: I changed a few things around in my sessionhelper to finally get it working. Had I had that correct from the get go, your solution would have worked immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using some kind of RESTfull controller, and you are rendering your form on action :new. So, to solve your trouble, add

```
@update = current_user.updates.build(params[:update])
```

to your **new** action

Comment: Tried this but I didn't have much luck with it. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: By the way, you are not in UpdatesController? If you are in view_pages_controller, that is the cause. In your environment you are rendering partial w form without instance variable. Define an @update instance in correspnding action of your view_pages_controller

Comment: I added your suggested code to the ViewPages Controller, however it just gives me an error about not knowing what 'updates' is.

Comment: Yes, it is in the User class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a debugger in above the line in your controller where you declare @update.

You could then see your current_user object and what methods are available using something like current_user.methods

Answer (score 0):

Have you included `resource:'updates' or resources:'updates'` in routes.rb.This may solve the problem.